# Best way(run-time) to aggregate (calculate ratio of) sum to total count based on group by

Tags: pandas, python-3.6, calculation

I'm trying to identify ratio of approved applications(identified by flag '1' and if not then '0') to total applications for each person(Cust_ID). I have achieved this logic by the following code but it takes about 10 mins to compute this for 1.6 M records. Is there a faster to perform the same operation?

```
# Finding ratio of approved out of total applications
df_approved_ratio = df.groupby('Cust_ID').apply(lambda x:x['STATUS_Approved'].sum()/len(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need aggregate by `mean`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'STATUS_Approved':[0,1,0,0,1,1],
                   'Cust_ID':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   STATUS_Approved Cust_ID
0                0       a
1                1       a
2                0       a
3                0       b
4                1       b
5                1       b

df_approved_ratio = df.groupby('Cust_ID')['STATUS_Approved'].mean()
print (df_approved_ratio)
Cust_ID
a    0.333333
b    0.666667
Name: STATUS_Approved, dtype: float64

print (df.groupby('Cust_ID').apply(lambda x:x['STATUS_Approved'].sum()/len(x)))
Cust_ID
a    0.333333
b    0.666667
Name: STATUS_Approved, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Using mean is faster and a great alternative to my question. Thanks! On a side note, could you help me if there are more than 2 status(categories)? I'm currently worked on a column with 4 status' values.

Comment: @Harish - Yes, My problem is need go home, so try create new question. Please add some sample data and expected output, be free modify my sample data. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Appreciate your prompt response!

Comment: @Harish Sorry, just see your comment, so added better and faster answer. I hope it working well. Answer was created by mobile phone, so no output and no nice formating.