# Aggregate (calculate the ratio of) a particular category from multiple categories grouped by unique IDs

Tags: pandas, python-3.6, calculation

As a follow-up to my previous question,
[Best way(run-time) to aggregate (calculate ratio of) sum to total count based on group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519379/)
(Thanks to @jezrael)

my another column has 4 different statuses - say 1,2,3,4

I'm now trying to find the ratio of 1s for each ID.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'STATUS':[1,2,1,3,4,1,2,3,1,1],'Cust_ID':list('aaabbbccdd')})
```

Desired Output:

## Finding the ratio of 1s for each ID

```
Cust_ID 
a    0.66667
b    0.33333
c    0.00000
d    1.00000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mean` of boolean mask created by `eq` (==) for one column `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df['STATUS'].eq(1).groupby(df['Cust_ID']).mean().to_frame()
#alternative
#df1 = (df['STATUS'] == 1).groupby(df['Cust_ID']).mean().to_frame()
print (df1)
           STATUS
Cust_ID          
a        0.666667
b        0.333333
c        0.000000
d        1.000000
```

Of for 2 column `df`:

```
df1 = df['STATUS'].eq(1).groupby(df['Cust_ID']).mean().reset_index()
#alternative
#df1 = (df['STATUS'] == 1).groupby(df['Cust_ID']).mean().reset_index()
print (df1)
  Cust_ID    STATUS
0       a  0.666667
1       b  0.333333
2       c  0.000000
3       d  1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution performed better!

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
 df.groupby('Cust_ID')['STATUS'].apply(lambda x: (x == 1).mean())
```

Output:

```
Cust_ID
a    0.666667
b    0.333333
c    0.000000
d    1.000000
Name: STATUS, dtype: float64
```